# Unable to make an element move diagonally with jQuery animate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, script-tag

Alright so I only need to learn JQuery for a couple of animations on a site I'm building.

I've been reading the tutorials on the JQuery site and am just trying to implement a simple diagonal move animation.

I'm still extremely new to JQuery (as in, started today) but from everything i understand, the following code should work. What error am i making?

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JQuery.js">
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#moveme").click(function(event){
    $("#moveme").animate({right: '+=50', bottom: '+=50'}, 1000);​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ 
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="moveme">
Move this text
</div>
</body>
```

**Edit:**

Added relative property from css and fixed parenthesis issue with `document` but still not working.

Comment: Sorry, accidentally pasted the wrong copy of the code, with a couple syntax errors. Updated version posted now.

Comment: Your question title should reflect the problem.

Comment: @user1787489: For future reference, note that the edit button lets you make changes to your existing question, which is what you probably should have done after reading Diodeus' comment

Comment: Oh, i didnt know you could edit the title too. Ok, thanks! Ahh, you edited it for me, great.

Comment: I tried some code. Check out in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you forgot some parenthesis to select the elements correctly.

What about that?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#moveme").click(function(event){
        $(this).animate({right: '+=50', bottom: '+=50'}, 1000);​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ 
    });
});
```

**Edit:**

Also, *make sure that you are importing the jQuery script library*:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ohhh, document has to be parenthesized too? So i guess that EVERY time you reference an element of the dom it has to be as such?

Comment: @user1787489 Hmm, strange.. Are you sure that you have imported jQuery? See my edited answer, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You missed $(document) in the line

> $document.ready(function(){

Answer (score 1):

Also
your jquery animate function is changing CSS of your id="moveme"

i'd make sure that in your css you have this.

```
#id {
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#moveme").click(function(event){
      $(this).animate({'margin-left': '+=50', 'margin-top': '+=50'}, 1000); 
    });
});​
```

Working demo here (just click on the div saying 'hello'): http://jsfiddle.net/px2jz/