# How can there be 2 lines of code which are exactly the same where one works and one does not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error

I recently posted a question in regards to a piece of jquery code that wasnt working.

[Unable to make an element move diagonally with jQuery animate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183759/unable-to-make-an-element-move-diagonally-with-jquery-animate)

I couldnt figure out what was wrong so i took another similar piece of code and slowly modified it bit by bit until it was exactly the same as my code that was supposed to be working, and this second copy worked while my first didnt.

So then i went line by line copying the code from the second and replacing the code in the first.

In the end what fixed it was replacing:

```
$(this).animate({left:'+=250'}, 1000);
```

with

```
$(this).animate({left:'+=250'}, 1000);
```

How is it possible that the first didnt work but the second did?

I know that if you copy quotes, as in `"`, from certain sources they will paste a slightly different character that doesnt work, but I'm not sure how to explain the above mentioned.

I triple checked them side by side and started replacing the first one character by character to see the culprit, but my dreamweaver crashed on me :(.

So, anyone know how this happened?

Comment: my guess would be `'` vice the `

Comment: Most likely you copied it from a website and it had an extra hidden character at the end (common when pasted there from jsfiddle)

Comment: Check console for errors, if there is any for 'UNEXPECTED TOKEN' without any character you've probably inserted some invisible special char in there. Had the same issue while ago.

Comment: jsFiddle and other random things do this a lot when copy/pasting from them! It's the `unexpected token` that @Killah's talking about... or the quote on the ~tilda key (`) instead of '

Comment: Great answers guys! That makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the code from your previous question:

```
$("#moveme").animate({right: '+=50', bottom: '+=50'}, 1000);​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ 
                        // ----right here------------------^
```

Toward the end of that line, you have about 15 or so invisible characters that are invalid.

When I highlight the code in Firefox, I can see that the height of the highlighting is taller right there. And when I go into *"edit"* mode, it takes several keystrokes to move the cursor past that point.

Comment: Wow, good call. This will help my troubleshootin gin the future. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

There are extra characters in the answer. When pasted into notepad++ this is what i see.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#moveme").click(function(event){
        $(this).animate({right: '+=50', bottom: '+=50'}, 1000);??????????????? 
    })
})
```